# Issue with ng-bs3-datepicker required field in angular

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, pug

I have a form and am getting a strange error when it comes to a required field "Date_Of_Birth". When I console the form, I get 2 values under form.$error.required for this field. As a result of which I get 2 notifications when the field is not entered

When I console the form in angular

```
div.containerBackground(ng-controller='GeneralReportsController')
div#primary1.container.cstm-panel-heading       
    div#primary2.align_input
        div.container.col-lg-12
            div.row.col-md-12 
                form.form-horizontal
                    div.form-group
                        label.col-sm-4 Select Special Program
                        div.col-sm-8
                            select#idType.btn.btn-default(name ='specialProgram',ng-model='specialProgram',ng-options='specialProgram.name for specialProgram in SpecialProgramDetails',ng-change='selectSpecialPrograme(specialProgram)' required)
                                | {{specialProgram.programName}}
                div(ng-show="program")
                    ng-form.login-form.form-horizontal.no_border(method="post" role="form" name="AddStudentsTospecialProgramForm")

                        div.form-group
                            label.col-sm-4 Date Of Birth
                                label.mandatoryField *
                            div.col-sm-8
                                ng-bs3-datepicker(name='Date_Of_Birth', ng-model='student.dob',date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" , language='en', required, ng-blur="validateDate(student.dob)")
                                p.help-block(ng-show='AddStudentsTospecialProgramForm.Date_Of_Birth.$error.pattern') Date Of Birth is invalid.


                        div.col-sm-offset-4.col-sm-10
                            a.btn.btn-success(role="button",ng-click='saveStudentRegistrationForSpecialProgram()') Register
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of the required attribute, I changed it to ng-required and the issue was fixed